# Como criar um unico botão para ligar e desligar lampada para arduino em html?

Tags: php, html, arduino

Boa tarde pessoal!! Sou novato de tudo no universo de programação, mas estou me aventurando com arduino, php e html!! Gostaria de saber como passar dois valores em um único botão em html. Tipo ao clicar uma vez chamar um arquivo .php e acender a lampada e ao clicar uma outra vez chamar outro arquivo .php e apagar a lampada.  Alguém poderia me ajudar???

Segue o código php para acender a lampada :

```
   $port = fopen("COM1", "w");
            fwrite($port, "1");
            header ("Location:../index.html");
            fclose($port);
```

Desde já agradeço a todos!!

Comment: Nenhuma resposta ajudou, @BrunoCosta?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) em conjunto com o [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/), dá pra personalizar e deixar com uma aparência de um interruptor.

Para a funcionalidade, utilizarei `AJAX` para fazer a chamada ao `PHP`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#switch', function() {

    selectedValue = (this.checked ? 1 : 0);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'arduino.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {switch : selectedValue},
        success: function() {
            alert("Ok!")
        }
    });

});
```

No seu arquivo `arduino.php` faça a alteração:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['switch'])) {
    $port = fopen("COM1", "w");
    fwrite($port, $_POST['switch']);
    fclose($port);  
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!! Vou Testar.

Answer (score 0):

Excelente amigo!! Agradeço grandemente, segui seu conselho e consegui fazer o botão com bootstrap, na base de copiar e colar kkkkk. Só não sei onde coloco seu código no html. 
Segue o código html que fiz:

Lembrando que sou leigo no assunto
:D

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.bootstraptoggle.com">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.3/styles/github.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="doc/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Exemplo simples</h3>
      <p>Teste de botao funcionando</p>
      <div class="example">
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
      </div>
      <script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```